# Write bytes in a USB disk directly

Tags: c#, windows, security, usb

We all know that USB disk has a flash inside it to store the data but along with the filesystem like FAT/NTFS etc. 
My requirement is to write the data on the flash not enveloped on a file or a file system i.e. data shall be placed in the flash directly without any file/filesystem.
Is it possible , if yes then how.

Comment: maybe you can explain what you want to do ? I mean what and not how

Comment: This is not the right type of question for Stack Overflow, please check out [the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more information. Generally, you should try something for yourself first and then report back here when things are not working correctly and show what code you have tried

Comment: It seems you are using Windows. How do you expect Windows to recognize and interact with your USB drive, if it has incompatible or no Filesystem? A storage device is of no use if it has no filesystem that the OS understands.

Comment: @msiyer  I expect that he probably does not want windows to be able to interact with the drive - rather to have a bespoke application which it alone can read/write to the drive in some proprietary/secret format.  Perhaps as some means to effect a degree of security?

Comment: So he may be looking for File System Filters. Look into : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial

Comment: @Nitin: What you are looking for is accessing a drive as "\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE1" via WinAPI CreateFile(..). This allows you to access all sectors in RAW mode. This will work with any drive installed just increase the number after pysicaldrive. Of course this requires admin permission.

Comment: @Robert On Windows Vista and later it won't work even for Admin without a kernel-mode driver or our RawDisk product.

Comment: @Eugene It will will only fail if there are partitions defined on the drive. As long as there are no partitions the disk can be read and written as physicaldrive if you are admin.

Answer (score 3):

That's posiible, but not with C#. You'll need to write kernel-mode driver-filter using C (or C++) to do that. Unfortunately, I can't recommend any good literature in English, but a good place to start might be [Microsoft Installable File System Kit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/gg463062) and its documentation.